# remember me(isPersistent) dont work on Forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

Here my cookie create code:
This is controller (model.RememberMe is a checkbox value)

```
int timeout = (model.RememberMe) ? (int) FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes : Session.Timeout;//4h
                    HttpCookie cookie = accountService.GetCookie(userId, model.RememberMe, timeout);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    Logger.Debug("POST: AccountController LogOn end.");
                    result = returnUrl != null
                        ? RedirectToLocal(returnUrl)
                        : RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile", new {id = userId});
```

Service method that's create cookie

```
public HttpCookie GetCookie(int userId, bool rememberMe, int timeout)
        {
            Logger.Trace("AccountService GetCookie start with arguments:" +
                         " userId = {0}, rememberMe = {1}.", userId, rememberMe);
            var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                               1,
                               Convert.ToString(userId),
                               DateTime.Now,
                               DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout),
                               rememberMe,
                               string.Empty,
                               "/"
                               );
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
            Logger.Debug("Cookie for user with userId = {0} has created", userId);
            Logger.Trace("AccountService GetCookie end.");
            return cookie;
        }
```

But unfortunately RememberMe dont work and cookies expires at the end of the browser session.Why?

[What is the purpose of FormsAuthenticationTicket isPersistent property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345817/what-is-the-purpose-of-formsauthenticationticket-ispersistent-property) Here some kind of answer but i dont understand why it doesnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between your code and the SO answer that you linked is that they use:

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);`

Which makes the cookie with proper expiration time based on the `IsPersistent` property. However, if you return the cookie with the constructor like in your code:

`HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));`

Then the expiration time will be set to browser-session because that is the default behavior of the `HttpCookie` class: [what is the default expiration time of a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002254/what-is-the-default-expiration-time-of-a-cookie)

So you probably have two options. Use the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` method outlined in the answer you linked to, or add:

`cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10); // or whatever you want`